# Debouncing Openlayers Events

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to perform a pretty intensive task within the listener for *zoomend* event of OpenLayers.

I figured that it would be prudent to use something like [Ben Alman's jQuery Throttle-Debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) in order to prevent this listener from executing too many times when the user clicks the zoom control very quickly consecutively.

So I am attempting code like the following, but it just doesn't work. The callback within the *$.debounce()* within the *zoomend* listener callback just never executes. Just to confirm if I remove the debounce functionality the listener callback for *zoomend* does execute.

```
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{
        eventListeners: {
            zoomend: function(event) {
                //execute 300ms after user stops zooming
                $.debounce(300,function(event) {
                    //..computationally intensive task
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

What am I doing wrong??

And should I even bother with debouncing??

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was just using $.debounce() incorrectly. Here is the corrected code:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{
    eventListeners: {
        'zoomend': $.debounce(1000,function() {
            //..computationally intensive task
        })
    }
});
```

Just to comment on this, I think it is beneficial to use the debouncing and am surprised that something like this hasn't been documented yet. When zoooming a user can tend to click the zoom buttons rapidly, and in many cases the redrawing at the new zoom level would depend on calculations using the value and resolution of the new zoom level. Therefore it would only make sense to do these calculations once the user has stopped zooming.
I believe this would also apply to panning.